# Ruby Gem not install dependency

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created a Ruby Gem and published it. I tried downloading it and I keep getting cannot require my dependent gem. The code is at https://github.com/wallerjake/toolshed and the gem in question is httparty. The error that I am getting is

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@sullivan_cotter/bundler/gems/toolshed-46404c5af06d/lib/toolshed.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)

I have updated my https://github.com/wallerjake/toolshed/blob/master/toolshed.gemspec to use add_dependency instead but that doesn't seem to be helping. Could it be conflicting with other Gems?

Answer (score 0):

The version on rubygems is still the old one with only development dependencies. Worked fine when I downloaded and built you gem from Github.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified development dependency, but call the `rake` form binary, just put *rake* gem dependency into usual `add_dependency`, and remove `::gem` call to:

**bin/toolshed**:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'toolshed'
require 'rake'
```

One again question: for what do you need the binary?

The **toolshed.gemspec** seems correct. How do you call it? Remove the installed gem with `gem uninstall toolshed` including binary. Make sure that the `bundle install`, and then call to `bundle exec bin/toolshed.rb` is correct after patching the dependencies.

After that generate the gem with `gem build toolshed.gemspec`, and install the gem with `gem install toolshed-0.0.4.gem`. Make sure that binary works. Only then publish the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sorry I solved this by adding them as a dependency not a development dependency.

`spec.add_dependency "httparty"
spec.add_dependency "json"
spec.add_dependency "pivotal-tracker"`